# Expand a range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

first post here.
I was wondering if anyone knows how to expand cells to list out all numbers between 2 numbers. For example if I input 1 on a1 and 6 on a2 it would move 6 to a6 and apply the rest of the series to the lines between.

Comment: Can you show the output here? You can paste excel screen shot here.

Answer (score 0):

Something very basic:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Mn As Long, Mx As Long, X As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A:A").Clear
    Mn = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Minimum", Type:=1)
    Mx = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Maximum", Type:=1)
    If Mn > 0 And Mx > 0 Then
        For X = Mn To Mx
            .Cells(X, 1).Value = X
        Next X
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Assign the macro to a button.